# How to create a custom Matrix?

Tags: math, matrix, linear-algebra, transpose

I have 2 matrices(yellow color) as follows:
matrix 1 (size of 4x1) and matrix 2 (size of 1x6),

I am allowed to use matrix unit,matrix inverse, transpose matrix function ,square matrix also [multiplication, addition and subtraction,..calculation] from 2 above matrix

**Edit:** the **numbers 1** in the 4x6 matrix are **not necessarily = 1**, as long as they are **nonzero**

*my question is*: how do I create a 4x6 matrix as in the image?
Actually, I find it quite similar to the diagonal matrix but I'm still stuck because I couldn't find the connection to deploy them!

Please give me a solution. Thanks very much!
[image]
Here's other types:

[image]

Comment: Are you asking *what combinations of the listed operations* will yield the 4x6 matrix shown?

Comment: Hi @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk: correct! as long as it is the direction to be able to solve this problem.

Comment: What's the relation between the 4x1 and 1x6 matrices and the 4x6 matrix?

Comment: @Joni: That is the problem to be solved: what combinations of the listed matrix operations applied to the 4x1 and the 1x6 will yield the 4x6.

Comment: If the ones don't mean == 1, then what do the blanks mean?

Comment: thanks, the empty =0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input vectors are X and Y, it looks like the output matrix Z is:

```
 Z(i,j)  =  1 when X(i)=Y(j)
            0 otherwise
```

If you have an element-wise comparison function, you can do this process. First multiply your vectors with a vector of ones, to produce matrices that have the rows or columns repeated.

```
1                      1 1 1 1 1 1
1  * [1 1 1 1 1 1]  =  1 1 1 1 1 1
2                      2 2 2 2 2 2
2                      2 2 2 2 2 2

1                      1 1 1 2 2 2
1  * [1 1 1 2 2 2]  =  1 1 1 2 2 2
1                      1 1 1 2 2 2
1                      1 1 1 2 2 2
```

An element-wise comparison of these two gives you the result you want.

```
1 1 1 1 1 1      1 1 1 2 2 2     1 1 1 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1  ==  1 1 1 2 2 2  =  1 1 1 0 0 0
2 2 2 2 2 2      1 1 1 2 2 2     0 0 0 1 1 1
2 2 2 2 2 2      1 1 1 2 2 2     0 0 0 1 1 1
```